# Glassfish V4 enabling/connecting jmx for remote access

Tags: glassfish, jmx, glassfish-4, jconsole

I have gone through lot of blogs etc but could not connect to my glassfish JMX remotely. I have below JVM settings -

```
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.local.only=false
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=8686
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=myremoteip
```

I am trying to access via console by using below string

```
service:jmx:rmi://myremoteip:8686/jndi/rmi://myremoteip:8686/jmxrmi
```

Above setup doesn't work and i am not sure how can i resolve it. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

In addtion to set JVM parameters listed above, in Glassfish Admin Console Configurations -> server-config -> Admin Service have to set:

- Address: server's IP address
- Security: not checked
- Port: 8686
- Realm name: admin-realm

If exists, delete JVM setting "-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=8686", this 
causes "Cannot start JMX connector JmxConnector config..." like exception!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote is not same as glassfish's own JMX server, but starts another JMX server in addition to servers existing one. I have not found any reasonable way to remotely connect to glassfish's own JMX yet.

If you change the -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port to for example 8786 you should be able to connect to the non-glassfish JMX just fine.